# JMeter not finding classes from jars in JMETER_HOME/lib/ext folder

Tags: java, performance, jmeter

I have created a simple Java class that extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient. I have also overridden its `runTest()` method. Then I created a jar file and pasted it into the `JMETER_HOME/lib/ext` folder. But when I am creating a test plan for Java requests, my class is not getting populated in the classnames drop down. Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Below is the code sample:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.solar.dcp.client;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.AbstractJavaSamplerClient;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSamplerContext;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

/**
 * @author dushyant.kumar.sahu
 * 
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BaseJavaSamplerClient extends AbstractJavaSamplerClient implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    public BaseJavaSamplerClient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private void simulateTest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        Employee emp1 = new Employee(34, "ShashiBhushan", 50000, 10475688);
        Employee emp2 = new Employee(29, "Anantha", 35000, 10765688);
        Employee emp3 = new Employee(32, "Nilesh", 60000, 10423688);
        Employee emp4 = new Employee(30, "Abhimanyu", 250000, 10983688);

        employees.add(emp1);
        employees.add(emp2);
        employees.add(emp3);
        employees.add(emp4);

        Collections.sort(employees, new EmployeeAgeComprator());
        System.out.println(
            "==============Sorting Employees by Age===============");

        for (Employee emp : employees) {
            System.out.println(emp.getName() + " : " + emp.getAge());
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n");

        System.out.println(
            "==============Sorting Employees by Name===============");

        Collections.sort(employees, new EmployeeNameComprator());

        for (Employee emp : employees) {
            System.out.println(emp.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SampleResult result = new SampleResult();

        try {

            result.sampleStart();
            System.out.println("Start the sample test");
            simulateTest();
            result.setSuccessful(true);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            result.setSuccessful(false);
        } finally {
            result.sampleEnd();
        }

        return result;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show JMeter.log file content ?

Answer (score 0):

Your class is strange, are you sure it compiles ?

It requires:

- Employee
- EmployeeAgeComprator

So you must first ensure it compiles and then also package all these dependencies in the JAR. If there any additional dependencies put them in jmeter/lib folder.